# operand type mismatch for 'jg' conditional branch with memory-indirect destination

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm doing x86 Assembly, 64bits

This is my `file.asm`

```
cmp rdi, 4
jg [rsi + 0x20]
jmp [rsi + rdi * 8]
```

and the error is `operand type mismatch for 'jg'`

I can't understand why the `jmp` is ok but the `jg` is not.

I'm using this code to compile `pwn asm -c amd64 -o output < file.asm`

Comment: That's just the way it is. `jmp` supports indirect target, `jg` does not. Consult an instruction set reference for available addressing modes.

Comment: Logically speaking, it's not necessary to overload the instruction set with every possible addressing mode for every type of jump, when a short conditional jump can easily be followed by an unconditional jump. Remember that the x86 design dates back to the days when CPUs only had thousands of transistors.

Comment: @sj95126: Also for code density, you wouldn't want to spend another 16 opcodes on indirect jcc with a modrm byte.  It's not needed very often, and even if you used the `0F` escape byte for 2-byte opcodes, that would mean 16 other 2-byte opcodes couldn't exist.  If it was valuable enough, they could have done it, but probably things like conditional-call would be higher on the list if adding new conditional branches.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out, you can't do conditional jumps to relative locations.

A solution for me was

```
cmp rdi, 4
jg foo

foo:
  jmp [rsi + 0x20]
```

Comment: More readable would be to make the opposite test `jle` to skip past the `jmp` (and to ensure the branch is in range).